# Why is this NDSolveValue function remembering past inputs?

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, evaluation

I have been attempting to generate a function that uses NDSolveValue to return the value of a solution to a system of ODE's when an event condition is triggered, as a function of the initial conditions.

When trying to evaluate this function for a couple of different inputs, I receive an error indicating that the "input value lies outside the range of data of the interpolating function". However, if I retype the function definition after every evaluation, I get no such error. **This suggests something in the definition is retaining knowledge that I've used the function before**, which is naturally undesirable. Is there any quick fix?

My code that replicates the error:

```
    testerror[a0_, b0_] := 
  NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][\[Omega]][t] ==  -10*\[Omega][t] + 
      10*Pi*a[t] + 10, Derivative[1][a][t] == \[Omega][t]*b[t] - a[t],
     Derivative[1][b][t] == -\[Omega][t]*a[t] - b[t] + 10, \[Omega][
      0] == -Sqrt[10*Pi - 1], a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, 
    WhenEvent[\[Omega][t] ==  -Sqrt[10*Pi - 1], end = t; 
     "StopIntegration"]}, {a[end], b[end]}, {t, \[Infinity]}];

testerror[-2.3, 2.5]; testerror[-2.35, 2.55]
```

If you re-evaluate the definition of the testerror function between evaluations however, you'll find no error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using a global variable `end`.

```
testerror[a0_, b0_] := 
 Block[{end}, 
  NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][\[Omega]][t] == -10*\[Omega][t] + 
   10*Pi*a[t] + 10, 
  Derivative[1][a][t] == \[Omega][t]*b[t] - a[t], 
  Derivative[1][b][t] == -\[Omega][t]*a[t] - b[t] + 10, \[Omega][
   0] == -Sqrt[10*Pi - 1], a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, 
  WhenEvent[\[Omega][t] == -Sqrt[10*Pi - 1], end = t;
  "StopIntegration"]}, {a[end], b[end]}, {t, \[Infinity]}]];


testerror[-2.3, 2.5];testerror[-2.35, 2.55]
```

You can see no error is produced after using `Block` to localize `end`.